# Planos de Testes no VSTS

Tags: c#, team-foundation-server, vsts

Estou tentando criar [Tests Plans](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts) no VSTS (versão Free), mas não estou encontrando o local indicado na documentação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invés disso, recebo essa interface:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por acaso a versão Free do VSTS não dispõe do recurso de testes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar essas funcionalidades você precisar ter uma assinatura do Visual Studio Enterprise ou ter instalada  extensão **Test Manager** que está disponível no **Visual Studio Marketplace**

Segue o link, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web

Comment: Nesse caso, nenhum tipo de teste é possível no VSTS sem essas duas opções?

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

Acessar a opção do Menu "Test Plans" > "Test Plans:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isto clicar na opção "New Test Plan":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]